# VS2010 C++ how to have different project references for each developer

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, msbuild

We are trying to move from C++ VS2005 to VS2010, but can't figure out how to move from the solution dependency model to the MSBuild project reference model.  We have multiple developers, but don't distribute all the source to each developer although each developer is provided with all the header files, .lib, and .dll files.

With VS2005, each developer has their own solution and sets up a project dependency to a project, unique to that developer, which includes all the .lib files they don't have source for.  This way, they can use the most current .vcproj files for the source they do have.

In trying to move to VS2010 / MSBuild, the project files now require that dependencies be included as references, yet some developers will not have a copy of the referenced project, only its .h and .lib.

Is there any way to combine the solution-based dependency model of VS2005/VS2008 with the MSBuild project reference model of VS2010?

Comment: Just put the .lib in the Additional Dependencies linker setting of the project.  That works either way.

Comment: Thanks very much, so far that seems to work.  Will give a more through test this week.

Answer (score 0):

MS removed implicit adding libraries in linker list once dependency added.

Now libs should be explicitly specified in Additional Dependencies of linker settings as well as includes in settings of compiler.